# ReactJS components for PDF export, Excel export and print

Tags: excel, reactjs, pdf, printing

I´m building some ReactJS `Table` and `Report` components tha basically will contain `<table>` data, some graphics (`d3`) and some textual data. I need to provide 3 buttons:

1. Export to PDF
2. Export to Excel
3. Print

Are there any trustable packages available for the tasks above using ReactJS ? What is the approach to handle these requirements ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a combination of the following JavaScript libraries:

[**React Csv**](https://github.com/abdennour/react-csv) is my favourite JavaScript library for working with csv. It excels at dynamic generation.

[**PDF Make**](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) is my favourite JavaScript library for generating PDFs.

Note: I would attach the files to this post, but there is currently no facility for this in StackOverflow.

Comment: Do these libraries work with server-side data as well?

Comment: No, these libraries only for front-end side using.

Comment: Unfortunately, `React Csv` doesn't have an excel format option.

Answer (score 1):

1. react-pdf (published 16 days ago - not tested)
2. react-export-excel (published 8 months ago - not tested)
3. For printing, put window.print() in your code

Example:
Copy and paste this as .html (in React, it would be onClick={window.print()} ... If I'm correct)

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Use the button below to print</p>
    <button id="print" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since I was looking for something similar, I ended up using :

1. [jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) (see specific issue for [reactjs](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/951))
2. [react-excel-workbook](https://github.com/ClearC2/react-excel-workbook)
3. nothing yet, feel free to update the answer if you have.